# how to upload local pdf files to google collab notebook?

Tags: python, file, google-colaboratory, pdf-parsing

I want to upload a local pdf into google collab and parse it with python.
How can I load the file so I could use with open?

Answer (score 0):

1. press on the file picture on the side bar (table of contents)
   [image]
2. press on "upload session to storage" and notice it now appears on the list below. [image]
3. right click on the 3 dots on the right side of the name of the file.   [image]
4. choose "copy path".
5. use this path in your code just as you would locally.

source: https://neptune.ai/blog/google-colab-dealing-with-files